# Manipulate JavaFX controllers from the use of another controller

Tags: java, javafx

I have this situation in a part of my JavaFX application. There are 2 `Slider`s and a `ToggleGroup` of `RadioButton`s that are returning a value in `acquisitionTimeValueLabel` when they are manipulated by the user. My question is: is there a way to have a `Slider` also for the acquistion time? So I can set it directly and the other controllers will be influenced from it. To be more clear, I would like to have the option to have also the inverse function.

*Also I am not very sure about the title of the question, so edits are very welcomed.*

**An example of my code:**

```
public class dasd {

private RadioButton first;
private RadioButton second;
private RadioButton third;
private ToggleGroup group;


private Slider ramWidthSlider = new Slider(0, 255, 0);
private Label ramWidthValueLabel = new Label("256 bytes (64 words)");

private Slider sampleRateSlider = new Slider (0, 15, 0);
private Label sampleRateValueLabel = new Label("13560 KHz");

private Label acquisitionTimeValueLabel = new Label ("some value");

private static final String[] STRINGS_FREQ = new String[16];
private static final String[] STRINGS_MEM = new String[256];



@FXML
private void initialize(){

    first.setToggleGroup(group);
    second.setToggleGroup(group);
    third.setToggleGroup(group);


    group.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((ov, old_toggle, new_toggle) -> {

        if (group.getSelectedToggle() != null) {
                        }
    });

    fillTheClock();
    fillTheRam();

    ramWidthValueLabel.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.createStringBinding(
                    () -> getDisplayMemory((int) Math.round(ramWidthSlider.getValue())),
                    ramWidthSlider.valueProperty()
            )
    );


    sampleRateValueLabel.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.createStringBinding(
                    () -> getDisplayFrequency((int) Math.round(sampleRateSlider.getValue())),
                    sampleRateSlider.valueProperty()
            )
    );

    acquisitionTimeValueLabel.textProperty().bind(
            Bindings.createStringBinding(
                    () -> String.format("%.3f", (pow(2, (group.getToggles().indexOf(group.getSelectedToggle()))))
                                    * (pow(2, sampleRateSlider.getValue()) / 13.56) * 64 * (ramWidthSlider.getValue() + 1) ) + " µs of acquisition",
                            group.selectedToggleProperty(), ramWidthSlider.valueProperty(), sampleRateSlider.valueProperty()
                    )
            ); 
}        




/**\
 * Methods for displaying the values of the Sample Rate Slider
 *
 */
private static void fillTheClock() {
    double frequency = 13560;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
        STRINGS_FREQ[i] = Double.toString(frequency) + " KHz";
        frequency = frequency / 2;
    }
}

private static String getDisplayFrequency(int value) {
    return STRINGS_FREQ[value];
}


/**
 * Methods for displaying the values of Memory Width Slider
 *
 */
private static void fillTheRam() {
    int memory = 256 ;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        STRINGS_MEM[i] = Integer.toString(memory) + " bytes (" + Integer.toString(memory/4) + " words)";
        memory = memory + 256;
    }
}

private static String getDisplayMemory(int value){
    return STRINGS_MEM[value];
}
}
```

Comment: Your function boils down to `aquisitionTime = 2^(toggleIndex + sampleRate) * 64 / 13,56 * (ramWidth + 1)` which surely can be resolved for all the variables, but there are a few issues with this: There are 4 variables and only one can be considered fixed. Even when you consider `toggleIndex` to be fixed, you still have 2 variables that can be adjusted to satisfy the equation. Moreover you combine exponentiation and multiplication so the effect of changing some of the variables is much greater for some of the variables compared to others...

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question will you want to edit a label value from 3 different sources the third one is directly edit the label value which will affect the first two:

So you can make the third slider and `listen` to the changes of it's value like so:

```java
slider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        //write your logic here where newValue if the current value of the slider
    }
});
```

in this method you can do your logic to edit the values of the other sliders.
I hope it helps

Comment: this I know of course, however this does not answer to my question. The comment by fabian explains the problem I am having to implement the solution.